# How to use WM_UNICHAR at example (C#)

Tags: c#, sendmessage

I can't find how I can use WM_UNICHAR to send any letters.
(WM_CHAR work good, but it can't send "я")

Ok, thi's work code to use WM_CHAR, but how use WM_UNICHAR I don't know..

Thi's didn't work:

```
SendMessage(handle, KeyboardMessages.WM_UNICHAR, val, new IntPtr(0));
```

Comment: Please add the code you have now.

Comment: Ok, I change post, can u halp me?

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot but with the addition of the code hopefully other reader(s) can.

Comment: There's no point in generating WM_KEYDOWN/UP, just send WM_CHAR.

Comment: WM_CHAR is work. I need WM_UNICHAR :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been... over a decade, but I think the answer is to use:

```
SendMessageW
```

(for wide) I believe you can change your `DllImport` to:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessageW"]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, KeyboardMessages ev, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```